# Drawing no intersected polygon with dragging vertexes

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, vertex

I'm trying to draw a polygon without intersecting.

Below is good example which I want to.

[image]

Bad example what I want to prevent.

[image]

If I choose red dot one, then what algorithm I can apply to prevent the intersecting sides of the polygon?

Comment: You need to implement a "polygon simplicity test". In your case, it is enough to check that the two edges leading to the moving vertex cross no other edge.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn’t know anything about this. You gave me good priming answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technical answer:**

The moving point must belong to the visibility zones of its two neighbors (ignoring the two adjoining edges).

[image]

You can construct these two zones and their intersection once for all, then constrain the cursor to remain in the intersection. This can be made efficiently in time O(Log(N)) per query, after some preprocessing. But this is quite complex and not worth the effort.

### [image]

**Practical answer:**

Simply check that the two edges from the moving point do not intersect the remaining edges.

Comment: I checked all remaining edges with two adjacent edges of the point as the practical answer. It's very simple and it works. :) Moreover there was no performance issue as far as I concerned.

Comment: @tae: sure, for small numbers of vertices (say below one million), you will not notice the running time.